# strange asterisk expansion in bash

Tags: bash, glob

Strange asterisk expansion

```
#!/bin/bash
my_IP=$(curl -m 5   -s  icanhazip.com)
rv=$?
szOut="--- curl error ($rv) ---"
if [ $rv -eq 0 ]; then
    szOut="*** today my IP is {$my_IP} ***"
fi
echo $szOut
exit 0
```

Under rv=0 I expected "*** today my IP is {80.29.32.166} ***

but got

```
get_ip.sh llegir_ip_externa.sh my_crons send_ftp.sh welcome.sag today my IP is {80.29.32.166} get_ip.sh llegir_ip_externa.sh my_crons send_ftp.sh welcome.sag
```

This is, the 3 asterisks expand into the list of files in this directory - 2 times, one at begin of line, other at end.

I fixed my problem changing "***" into "+++",
but now I want to know the origin of this "expansion",
as I use asterisks quite often.

Any pointer, URL, or PDF is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: [Glob Expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) : "Globbing interprets the standard wild card characters * and ?, character lists in square brackets, and certain other special characters"

Comment: Paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: The solution is "do double quote" :

Comment: #!/bin/bash
    szOut="*** --- curl."
    echo "$szOut"
    exit 0